# $\mathbb{C}$ is biholomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$*?

Tags: complex-analysis

I have to decide wether $\mathbb{C}$ is biholomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$* or not.

I have thought about the exponential function $f:\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^*$,  $z \rightarrow e^{z}$ which is holomorphic and whose inverse is the logarithm, but I am not sure if this is right.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is $\Bbb C$ homeomorphic to $\Bbb C^*$?

Comment: as noted above $\mathbb{C}^*$ is not simply connected so the two cannot be even homeomorphic, not to speak of biholomorphic; however $\mathbb C$ is the universal cover of $\mathbb{C}^*$, so there is a *local* biholomorphic map as you noted

Comment: About your specific $f$, note that it isn't one-to-one, and its inverse, the logarithm, isn't well-defined until you choose a particular branch --- and then it isn't continuous.